# Movie Review Classification with Recurrent Networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

As far as I know and research, the sequences in a data set can be of different lengths; we do not need to pad or truncate them provided that each batch in the training process contains the sequences with the same length.

To realize and apply it, I decided to set the batch size to 1 and trained my RNN model over the IMDB movie classification dataset. I added the code that I had written below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import imdb
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import SimpleRNN
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding

max_features = 10000
batch_size = 1

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=10000, output_dim=32))
model.add(SimpleRNN(units=32, input_shape=(None, 32)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", 
                  loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["acc"])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
                     batch_size=batch_size, epochs=10, 
                     validation_split=0.2)
```

```
acc = history.history["acc"]
loss = history.history["loss"]
val_acc = history.history["val_acc"]
val_loss = history.history["val_loss"]

epochs = range(len(acc) + 1)
plt.plot(epochs, acc, "bo", label="Training Acc")
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, "b", label="Validation Acc")
plt.title("Training and Validation Accuracy")
plt.legend()
plt.figure()
plt.plot(epochs, loss, "bo", label="Training Loss")
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, "b", label="Validation Loss")
plt.title("Training and Validation Loss")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

What error I have been encountered is to fail to convert the input to tensor format because of the list components in the input numpy array. However, when I change them, I continue to get similar kinds of errors.

The error message:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

I could not handle the problem. Could anyone help me on this point?

Answer (score 2):

### With Sequence Padding

There are two issues. You need to use `pad_sequences` on the text sequence first. And also there is no such param `input_shape` in [`SimpleRNN`](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/simple_rnn/). Try with the following code:

```
max_features = 20000  # Only consider the top 20k words
maxlen = 200  # Only consider the first 200 words of each movie review
batch_size = 1

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)
print(len(x_train), "Training sequences")
print(len(x_test), "Validation sequences")
x_train = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=maxlen)
x_test = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=maxlen)


model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=max_features, output_dim=32))
model.add(SimpleRNN(units=32))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["acc"])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, 
                         epochs=10, validation_split=0.2)
```

[Here](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/bidirectional_lstm_imdb/) is the official code example, it might help you.

---

### With Sequence Padding with Mask in Embedding Layer

Based on your comments and information, It seems that it's possible to use a **variable-length** input sequence, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189070/how-do-i-create-a-variable-length-input-lstm-in-keras) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925374/how-lstm-deal-with-variable-length-sequence) too. But still, I can say, in most of the cases practitioner would prefer to `pad` the sequences for uniform length; as it's convincing. Choosing non-uniform or variable input sequence length is some kind of special case; similar to when we want variable input image sizes for vision models.

However, here we will add info on `padding` and how we can `mask` out the padded value in training time which technically seems variable-length input training. Hope that convinces you. Let's first understand what `pad_sequences` do. Normally in sequence data, it's very much a common case that, each training samples are in a different length. Let's consider the following inputs:

```
raw_inputs = [
    [711, 632, 71],
    [73, 8, 3215, 55, 927],
    [83, 91, 1, 645, 1253, 927],
]
```

These 3 training samples are in different lengths, 3, 5, and 6 respectively. What we do next is to make them all equal lengths by adding some value (typically `0` or `-1`) - whether at the beginning or at the end of the sequence.

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
    raw_inputs, maxlen=6, dtype="int32", padding="pre", value=0.0
)

array([[   0,    0,    0,  711,  632,   71],
       [   0,   73,    8, 3215,   55,  927],
       [  83,   91,    1,  645, 1253,  927]], dtype=int32)
```

We can set `padding = "post"` to set pad value at the end of the sequence. But it recommends using `"post"` padding when working with `RNN` layers in order to be able to use the `CuDNN` implementation of the layers. However, FYI, you may notice we set `maxlen = 6` which is the highest input sequence length. But it does not have to be the highest input sequence length as it may get computationally expensive if the dataset gets bigger. We can set it to `5` assuming that our model can learn feature representation within this length, it's a kind of hyper-parameter. And that brings another parameter `truncating`.

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
    raw_inputs, maxlen=5, dtype="int32", padding="pre", truncating="pre", value=0.0
)

array([[   0,    0,  711,  632,   71],
       [  73,    8, 3215,   55,  927],
       [  91,    1,  645, 1253,  927]], dtype=int32
```

Okay, now we have a padded input sequence, all inputs are uniform length. Now, we can `mask` out those additional padded values in training time. We will tell the model some part of the data is padding and those should be ignored. That mechanism is **masking**. So, it's a way to tell **sequence-processing** layers that certain timesteps in the input are missing, and thus should be skipped when processing the data. There are three ways to introduce input **masks** in `Keras` models:

- Add a `keras. layers.Masking layer`.
- Configure a `keras.layers.Embedding` layer with `mask_zero=True`.
- Pass a mask argument manually when calling layers that support this argument (e.g. `RNN` layers).

Here we will show only by configuring the `Embedding` layer. It has a parameter called `mask_zero` and set `False` by default. If we set it `True` then `0` containing indices in the sequences will be skipped. `False` entry indicates that the corresponding timestep should be **ignored during processing**.

```
padd_input = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
    raw_inputs, maxlen=6, dtype="int32", padding="pre", value=0.0
)
print(padd_input)

embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=5000, output_dim=16, mask_zero=True)
masked_output = embedding(padd_input)
print(masked_output._keras_mask)

[[   0    0    0  711  632   71]
 [   0   73    8 3215   55  927]
 [  83   91    1  645 1253  927]]

tf.Tensor(
[[False False False  True  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True]], shape=(3, 6), dtype=bool)
```

And here is how it's computed in the class [`Embedding(Layer)`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/d71247dcd805e58110a784b03cf2fcbaa1c837c8/keras/layers/embeddings.py#L150).

```
  def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
    if not self.mask_zero:
      return None

    return tf.not_equal(inputs, 0)
```

And here is one catch,  if we set `mask_zero` as `True`, as a consequence, index `0` cannot be used in the vocabulary. According to the doc

> mask_zero: Boolean, whether or not the input value 0 is a special "padding" value that should be masked out. This is useful when using recurrent layers which may take variable length input. If this is `True`, then all subsequent layers in the model need to support masking or an exception will be raised. If mask_zero is set to True, as a consequence, index 0 cannot be used in the vocabulary (input_dim should equal size of vocabulary + 1).

So, we have to use `max_features + 1` at least. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43228596/9215780) is a nice explanation on this.

---

Here is the complete example using these of your code.

```
# get the data 
(x_train, y_train), (_, _) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)
print(x_train.shape)

# check highest sequence lenght 
max_list_length = lambda list: max( [len(i) for i in list])
print(max_list_idx(x_train))

max_features = 20000  # Only consider the top 20k words
maxlen = 350  # Only consider the first 350 words out of `max_list_idx(x_train)`
batch_size = 512

print('Length ', len(x_train[0]), x_train[0])
print('Length ', len(x_train[1]), x_train[1])
print('Length ', len(x_train[2]), x_train[2])

# (1). padding with value 0 at the end of the sequence - padding="post", value=0.
# (2). truncate 'maxlen' words 
# out of `max_list_idx(x_train)` at the end - maxlen=maxlen, truncating="post"
x_train = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, 
                                  maxlen=maxlen, dtype="int32", 
                                  padding="post", truncating="post", 
                                  value=0.)

print('Length ', len(x_train[0]), x_train[0])
print('Length ', len(x_train[1]), x_train[1])
print('Length ', len(x_train[2]), x_train[2])
```

Your model definition should be now

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(
           input_dim=max_features + 1,
           output_dim=32, 
           mask_zero=True))
model.add(SimpleRNN(units=32))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
```

```
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["acc"])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
                    batch_size=256, 
                    epochs=1, validation_split=0.2)

639ms/step - loss: 0.6774 - acc: 0.5640 - val_loss: 0.5034 - val_acc: 0.8036
```

---

**References**

- [Masking and padding with Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding)
- [Embedding layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/embedding/), - [Pads sequences](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/sequence/pad_sequences)
- [Recurrent Neural Networks (RNN) with Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn)

Answer (score 0):

### Without Sequence Padding

**Padding** is not MUST for the **variable length of the input sequence** in sequence modeling. In `TensorFlow`, a tensor with variable numbers of elements along some axis is called **ragged** and we use `tf.ragged.RaggedTensor` for ragged data. For example:

```
# variable length input sequences 
ragged_list = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [9]]

# convert to ragged tensor that handle such variable length inputs 
tf.ragged.constant(ragged_list).shape
shape: [4, None]
```

[image]

So, we can use **ragged** input data in sequence modeling and we no longer need to pad the sequence for uniform input length.

---

**DataSet**

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import warnings, numpy as np 
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=np.VisibleDeprecationWarning) 

# maxlen = 200 # No maximum length but whatever 
batch_size = 256
max_features = 20000  # Only consider the top 20k words

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = \
              tf.keras.datasets.imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)
print(len(x_train), "Training sequences")
print(len(x_test), "Validation sequences")

25000 Training sequences
25000 Validation sequences
```

```
# quick check 
x_train[:3]

array([list([1, 14, 22, 16, 43, 53, ....]),
       list([....]),
       list([...]),
```

**Convert to Ragged**

Now, we convert it to a ragged tensor which deals with variable size sequences.

```
x_train = tf.ragged.constant(x_train)
x_test  = tf.ragged.constant(x_test)
```

```
# quick check 

x_train[:3]
<tf.RaggedTensor [[1, 14, 22, 16, 43, 53, ...] [...] [...]]

x_train.shape, x_test.shape
(TensorShape([25000, None]), TensorShape([25000, None]))
```

**Model**

```
# Input for variable-length sequences of integers
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None,), dtype="int32")
# Embed each integer in a 128-dimensional vector
x = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(max_features, 128)(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(units=32)(x)
# Add a classifier
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, None)]            0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, None, 128)         2560000   
_________________________________________________________________
simple_rnn (SimpleRNN)       (None, 32)                5152      
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1)                 33        
=================================================================
Total params: 2,565,185
Trainable params: 2,565,185
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

**Compile and Train**

```
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["acc"])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2, 
          epochs=10, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

```
Epoch 1/10
113s 1s/step - loss: 0.6273 - acc: 0.6295 - val_loss: 0.4188 - val_acc: 0.8206
Epoch 2/10
109s 1s/step - loss: 0.4895 - acc: 0.8041 - val_loss: 0.4703 - val_acc: 0.8040
Epoch 3/10
109s 1s/step - loss: 0.3513 - acc: 0.8661 - val_loss: 0.3996 - val_acc: 0.8337
Epoch 4/10
110s 1s/step - loss: 0.2450 - acc: 0.9105 - val_loss: 0.3945 - val_acc: 0.8420
Epoch 5/10
109s 1s/step - loss: 0.1437 - acc: 0.9559 - val_loss: 0.4085 - val_acc: 0.8422
Epoch 6/10
109s 1s/step - loss: 0.0767 - acc: 0.9807 - val_loss: 0.4310 - val_acc: 0.8429
Epoch 7/10
109s 1s/step - loss: 0.0380 - acc: 0.9932 - val_loss: 0.4784 - val_acc: 0.8437
Epoch 8/10
110s 1s/step - loss: 0.0288 - acc: 0.9946 - val_loss: 0.5039 - val_acc: 0.8564
Epoch 9/10
110s 1s/step - loss: 0.0957 - acc: 0.9615 - val_loss: 0.5687 - val_acc: 0.8575
Epoch 10/10
109s 1s/step - loss: 0.1008 - acc: 0.9637 - val_loss: 0.5166 - val_acc: 0.8550
```