# Training Multiple Input and Output Keras Model (ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list))

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have six different `Sequnstial` Keras models and I desire to concatenate them like the following:

#### Models

```
activation = 'tanh'
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Dense(3, input_dim=3, activation=activation))
model1.add(Dense(3, activation=activation))
model1.add(Dense(1))

model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Dense(3, input_dim=3, activation=activation))
model2.add(Dense(3, activation=activation))
model2.add(Dense(1))

model3 = Sequential()
model3.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, activation=activation))
model3.add(Dense(1, activation=activation))
model3.add(Dense(1))

model4 = Sequential()
model4.add(Dense(6, input_dim=6, activation=activation))
model4.add(Dense(3, activation=activation))
model4.add(Dense(1))

model5 = Sequential()
model5.add(Dense(2, input_dim=2, activation=activation))
model5.add(Dense(2, activation=activation))
model5.add(Dense(1))

model6 = Sequential()
model6.add(Dense(6, input_dim=6, activation=activation))
model6.add(Dense(4, activation=activation))
model6.add(Dense(1))
```

#### Concatenation

```
model_concat = concatenate([model1.output, model2.output, model3.output, model4.output, model5.output, model6.output])

composed_model = Model(
    inputs=[model1.input, model2.input, model3.input, model4.input, model5.input, model6.input],
    outputs=model_concat
)
composed_model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.001), loss='mse')
```

The output dimensions of all models are 1, but the input dimensions of models are different. The above code will run completely without any error.

Now, the problem is for training the model. I will try to run the following code to train the model with one data instance (the dimension of each subarray is equal to the input dimension of the corresponding model):

```
x_input = [[[-50.0, -50.0, 10.0], [-10.0, -20.0, 30.0], \
            [20.0], [10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0], [50.0, 50.0],\
            [10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0]]]

y_output = [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,1.0,1.0]]
composed_model.fit(x_input, y_output)
```

However, I have the following error:

> ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).

I found a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58636087/3768871), but it does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell we can't just pass all **variable-size inputs** together in `fit` for the multi-input model. The way you pass your training pairs to the model, it surely unable to unpack for concern input layers. The related post that you mentioned is also an important fact to consider.

However, in `tensorflow`,  we can use `tf.ragged.RaggedTensor` for variable-length input sequence, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67063653/9215780). But not sure if there is any workaround possible by converting to the ragged tensor. It probably would possible if a single input layer takes a different length of the input sequence.

If you read the [fit method](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/)'s training pairs input you would see `keras` expects the `x` paramer as follows:

```
Arguments

x: Input data. It could be:
    1. A Numpy array (or array-like), or a list of arrays (in case the model 
       has multiple inputs).
    2. A TensorFlow tensor, or a list of tensors (in case the model 
       has multiple inputs).
    3. A dict mapping input names to the corresponding array/tensors, 
       if the model has named inputs.
...
...
```

For your case, option 3 is pretty convenient to choose from, which is passing the dictionary mapped input names with training pairs. Here is one way we can do this. First set some names to the input layer of each model. We set `model1`, `model2`, ... etc.

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense 

activation = 'tanh'
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Dense(3, input_dim=3, activation=activation, name='model1'))
model1.add(Dense(3, activation=activation))
model1.add(Dense(1))

model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Dense(3, input_dim=3, activation=activation, name='model2'))
model2.add(Dense(3, activation=activation))
model2.add(Dense(1))

model3 = Sequential()
model3.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, activation=activation, name='model3'))
model3.add(Dense(1, activation=activation))
model3.add(Dense(1))

model4 = Sequential()
model4.add(Dense(6, input_dim=6, activation=activation, name='model4'))
model4.add(Dense(3, activation=activation))
model4.add(Dense(1))

model5 = Sequential()
model5.add(Dense(2, input_dim=2, activation=activation, name='model5'))
model5.add(Dense(2, activation=activation))
model5.add(Dense(1))

model6 = Sequential()
model6.add(Dense(6, input_dim=6, activation=activation, name='model6'))
model6.add(Dense(4, activation=activation))
model6.add(Dense(1))
```

Now, build whole the final model where we also set the last layer name, which is set here as `target_concatenate`.

```
import tensorflow as tf 

model_concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(
    [
     model1.output, model2.output, model3.output, 
     model4.output, model5.output, model6.output
    ], name='target_concatenate')

composed_model = tf.keras.Model(
    inputs=[model1.input, model2.input, model3.input, 
            model4.input, model5.input, model6.input],
    outputs=model_concat
)
composed_model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')
```

**DataSet**

The sample data you provided is not legal for model training as we mentioned above. Firstly it should not be a `list` but `numpy` and secondly, for multi-input variable size, it convenient to pass them separately.

```
import numpy as np 

# Six Inputs 
one = np.random.randint(-50, 10, size=(1, 3))
two = np.random.randint(-10, 30, size=(1, 3))
thr = np.random.randint(20, size=(1))
fur = np.random.randint(10, size=(1, 6))
fiv = np.random.randint(50, size=(1,2))
six = np.random.randint(10, size=(1, 6))

# One Target
tar = np.random.randint(2, size=(1, 6))

print(one, one.shape)
print(two, two.shape)
print(thr, thr.shape)
print(fur, fur.shape)
print(fiv, fiv.shape)
print(six, six.shape)
print(tar, tar.shape)

[[-42   9 -34]] (1, 3)
[[28 22  7]] (1, 3)
[19] (1,)
[[4 4 1 7 4 7]] (1, 6)
[[40 35]] (1, 2)
[[3 6 1 1 3 8]] (1, 6)
[[0 0 1 1 0 0]] (1, 6)
```

When we call `.fit`, we will pass these datasets as dict mapping model's input and output names to the corresponding array. So, let's check to get the names of the composed model.

```
# viewing the model shapes and layers name 
# tf.keras.utils.plot_model(composed_model, 
#                            show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
composed_model.input_names, composed_model.output_names

(['model1_input',
  'model2_input',
  'model3_input',
  'model4_input',
  'model5_input',
  'model6_input'],
 ['target_concatenate'])
```

Great, now we can pass training Paris as follow conveniently to the `fit` method.

```
composed_model.fit(
    {
         "model1_input": one, "model2_input": two, "model3_input": thr,
         "model4_input": fur, "model5_input": fiv, "model6_input": six
     },
     {
         "target_concatenate": tar
     },
    epochs=10,
    batch_size=32,
    verbose=2
)
```

```
Epoch 1/10
496ms/step - loss: 0.6022
Epoch 2/10
5ms/step - loss: 0.5428
Epoch 3/10
7ms/step - loss: 0.4888
Epoch 4/10
16ms/step - loss: 0.4426
Epoch 5/10
8ms/step - loss: 0.4041
Epoch 6/10
8ms/step - loss: 0.3719
Epoch 7/10
9ms/step - loss: 0.3448
Epoch 8/10
5ms/step - loss: 0.3215
Epoch 9/10
7ms/step - loss: 0.3011
Epoch 10/10
5ms/step - loss: 0.2830
```