# Correct way to specify training data as tuple (x, y) in Keras model.fit with multiple inputs and outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, training-data

I am training a Keras Tensorflow model with three inputs and two outputs:

```
mymodel = tf.keras.Model([X1, X2, X3], [y1, y2])
```

When I fit this model by separately specifying `x` and `y` data, it works fine without any hitches:

```
history = mymodel.fit([X1, X2, X3], [y1, y2], batch_size=128, epochs=5)
```

However, I would like to provide the training data as a single tuple (x, y) in order to maintain compatibility with a custom data generator. When I do this, it throws an error:

```
data = ([X1, X2, X3], [y1, y2])
history = mymodel.fit(data, batch_size=128, epochs=5)
```

```
No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0',...
```

I guess my format for the `data` tuple is wrong.

How can I correctly specify my training data?

Answer (score 4):

What you need is to build your data pipeline with a generator or `tf.data` API. According to the documentation of the training API, [source](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/):

```
Model.fit(
    x=None,
    y=None,
    batch_size=None,
    epochs=1,
    ...
```

**Arguments**

```
- x: Input data. It could be:
     A tf.data dataset. Should return a tuple of either (inputs, targets) 
     or (inputs, targets, sample_weights).

     A generator or keras.utils.Sequence returning (inputs, targets) or 
    (inputs, targets, sample_weights).

- y: If x is a dataset, generator, or keras.utils.Sequence instance, 
     y should not be specified (since targets will be obtained from x).
```

FYI, but if your data is [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) array or [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) tensor (`x`), then you need to provide the corresponding `y`. According to the doc

```
- x: 
    A Numpy array (or array-like), or a list of arrays (in case the model has 
    multiple inputs).
    A TensorFlow tensor, or a list of tensors (in case the model has multiple inputs).

- y:
   Like the input data x, it could be either Numpy array(s) or TensorFlow tensor(s). 
   It should be consistent with x (you cannot have Numpy inputs 
   and tensor targets, or inversely).
```

Comment: Thank you! In that case, how can I use a dataset generator with numpy arrays (and multiple inputs/outputs).

Comment: [Here](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) is one good article regarding the keras generator. And [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) is the tutorial of tf.dataset API.

Comment: Those are for dataloader, in case of model definition, refer to this discussion, [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66845924/multi-input-multi-output-model-with-keras-functional-api/66849164#66849164), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67114215/training-multiple-input-and-output-keras-model-valueerror-failed-to-convert-a/67117135#67117135).

Comment: Some more resources for reference. https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html